# document.getElementById('').innerHTML simply not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not sure why this isn't working, there doesn't seem to be any typos and, to me, this is function code, however the

element does not change when the button is clicked. No error message. Any help appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Testing Page</h1>

<p id="hello">This will change.</p>

<p>
<button type="button" onclick="click()">Click Dis Ahlie</button>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function click(){document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML="Hello";}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try renaming your `click` function to something else e.g. `clickHandler`

Comment: Seeing any error in console?

Comment: Add within your function `console.log("Running clock function")` to see if your function is invoked at all.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj care to explain why `click()` doesn't work?

Comment: @ebyrob I think that's because javascript already has a function with that name. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click